# Find multiple database objects by attribute in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Track table and a Section table. A track has many sections. Sections are connected to their respective task by the Section's :track_id, which corresponds to the Track's :id attribute.

```
<% @track = Track.find(params[:id]) %>
<% @sections = Section.find_by_track_id(@track.id) %>
```

In the code above I'm trying to find multiple sections that share the same :track_id attribute, but find_by_track_id() only returns the first. What's the best way to get all of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where), which finds all records where a specific set of conditions are met.

```
@sections = Section.where(track_id: @track.id)
```

This is unrelated to your question, but you should set `@sections` and `@track` in your controller. As it seems like you're new to Rails, I'd highly recommend reading through the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/). They will help you immensely on your journey.

**EDIT:** I was solving for the general question of "Find multiple database objects by attribute in Rails?", which is how to find multiple database objects in the general case. @TarynEast's method is the way to go to find all of the `sections` for a `track`, or more generally, all of the objects that belong to the desired object. For the specific case you're asking for above, go with @TarynEast's solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm switching from Sinatra and the transition (in the last couple hours - this is my first Rails app) has been bumpier than I thought it would be. As soon as I claw my way to a functional page I'm going to refactor for MVC. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the transition!

Answer (score 6):

If your tracks and sections are related in this way, then the best way to relate them is by using the methods that come automatically from Rails' associations.

in this case, I expect in your model files, you have the following:

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sections
end
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :track
end
```

Then you can get the sections for a track like this:

```
@track = Track.find(params[:id])
@sections = @track.sections
```

Answer (score 3):

**Association**

To extend `Taryn East`'s answer, you need to look into [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

In your model, if you have the following [`has_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) relationship:

```
#app/models/track.rb
Class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sections
end

#app/models/section.rb
Class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :track
end
```

[image]

This will set up a [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) association between your `tracks` and `sections` datatables.

--

**Associative Data**

The **magic** of Rails comes into play here

When you call the "parent" object, you'll be able to locate it using its [`primary key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) (typically the `ID`). The magic happens when Rails automatically uses this `primary_key` as a `foreign_key` of the child model - allowing you to call all its data as an append to the parent object:

```
@track = Track.find params[:id] #-> find single Track by primary key
@sections = @track.sections #-> automagically finds sections using the track primary key
```

This means if you call the following, it will work exactly how you want:

```
@sections.each do |section|
    section.name
end
```

---

**Where**

Finally, if you wanted to look up more than one record at a time, you should identify which `ActiveRecord` method you should use:

- `find` is to locate a single record by `id`
- `finy_by key: "value"` is to locate a single record by your defined key/column
- `where` is to return multiple items using your own conditions

So to answer your base line question, you'll want to use `where`:

```
@sections = Section.where track_id: params[:id]
```

This is not the *right* answer, but it should help you

Answer (score -1):

```
    <% @sections=@track.sections%>
```

Comment: A bit of explanation is needed here rather than just a single line of code.

Comment: Yeah, you could probably combine your two answers as a good starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Use find when you are looking for one specific element identified by it's id.
`Model.find` is using the primary key column. Therefore there is always exactly one or no result.